# Pan keyboard in overlay

Tags: android

I have an Android application that adds a view to the window on startup. My view displays correctly but whenever I open the keyboard my view resizes so that it fits between the top of the screen and the top of the keyboard. I've tried setting the `softInputMode` to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` but this doesn't do anything. In fact, changing it to anything doesn't seem to have an effect.

The restrictions I have are:

- I have to display my view as an overlay (using `WindowManager.addView()`)
- I have to use `TYPE_PHONE`

My code so far:

```
    public DisplayManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.windowManager = (WindowManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        this.isDisplayed = false;

        this.layoutParameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
        /*this.layoutParameters.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        this.layoutParameters.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;*/
        this.layoutParameters.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN;
        this.layoutParameters.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        this.layoutParameters.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN;
    }

    public void show() {
        if (this.isDisplayed == false) {
            if (this.mainView == null)
                this.mainView = MainView_.build(this.context);

            this.windowManager.addView(this.mainView, this.layoutParameters);
            this.mainView.viewDisplayed();
            this.isDisplayed = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will be of help https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#ShowOnStart

Comment: Thanks @ElliotSchep, there was some good info there but nothing that helps specifically with this issue I'm facing